# Flutter does not output all the results during a post request

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, post, http-post

Flutter does not output all the results during a post request. Out of about 260 comes to the list, 113 are saved.

...............................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
Future<List<NewChatModel>> getAllChats({@required String userId}) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(URL),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, int>{
      'first_user_id': int.parse(userId),
    }),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List<NewChatModel> returnList = [];
    for (var i in jsonDecode(response.body)) {
      returnList.add(NewChatModel.fromJson(i));
    }
    print(returnList.length);
    return returnList;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

    class NewChatModel {
  String id;
  String chatId;
  String messageId;
  String message;
  String messageDate;
  String schoolId;
  String fullName;
  String phone;
  String email;
  String urlProfileImage;
  String birthday;
  String roleId;
  String lastActivity;
  String isOnline;

  NewChatModel(
      {this.id,
      this.chatId,
      this.messageId,
      this.message,
      this.messageDate,
      this.schoolId,
      this.fullName,
      this.phone,
      this.email,
      this.urlProfileImage,
      this.birthday,
      this.roleId,
      this.lastActivity,
      this.isOnline});

  factory NewChatModel.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return NewChatModel(
      id: json['id'].toString(),
      chatId: json['chat_id'].toString(),
      messageId: json['message_id'].toString(),
      message: json['message'].toString(),
      messageDate: json['message_date'].toString(),
      schoolId: json['school_id'].toString(),
      fullName: json['full_name'].toString(),
      phone: json['phone'].toString(),
      email: json['email'].toString(),
      urlProfileImage: json['urlProfileImage'].toString(),
      birthday: json['birthday'].toString(),
      roleId: json['role_id'].toString(),
      lastActivity: json['last_activity'].toString(),
      isOnline: json['is_online'].toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: added NewChatModel code
But I don`t think that its help solve problem
I think problem in String limit, idk

Comment: could you please add NewChatModel class?

Comment: Do you mean that when you print `returnList.length`, the value is smaller than the expected length?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård yes, you right

Comment: How about the values that you do get, are they of the expected type? `response.body`, that doesn't sound like a chat!... That sounds like a key-value pair......

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård Yes, they have the expected type, but I think that's not the problem at all. I just checked the received STRING and everything is there, for some reason the list can`t handle everything

Comment: Do me a favor! Change the "var i" in your code into the specific data type. Using "var" in a for-loop like that is looking for trouble... You don't really know what you are looping through! Probably that's where your error is.

Comment: Another tip would be to add a `print('i is $i of type ${i.runtimeType}');` in the for-loop. So you know exactly what your "i" actually is! I suspect it isn't exactly what you think it is...

Comment: Plz clarify what your `response.body` is? Of what type is it and what does it contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why this is so, but here is the answer to my question :)

For some reason, he doesn't want to show the entire length of the list, but he filled it out absolutely correctly)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If at all it helps you, I have a list of chat conversations in my app, too. I collect them with a `Stream` and display them with a `StreamBuilder()`. This is a very resource efficient way to do it, without the need to actually collect all the conversations at once! The `StreamBuilder()` widget makes sure it collects only the conversations that are currently visible on the screen (plus some).

This is what it looks like:

```
import 'package:my_giggz/firebase_labels.dart';
import 'package:my_giggz/my_firebase.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyMessagesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyMessagesScreenState createState() {
    return _MyMessagesScreenState();
  }
}

class _MyMessagesScreenState extends State<MyMessagesScreen> {
  String myUid = MyFirebase.authObject.currentUser!.uid;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        // Stream of all the conversations in the database that contain my uid:
        stream: MyFirebase.storeObject.collection(kCollectionConversations).where(kFieldParticipantsArray, arrayContains: myUid).orderBy(kFieldLastTimeStamp, descending: true).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
          List<Widget> convCards = [];
          QuerySnapshot? foundConversations = asyncSnapshot.data;
          if (foundConversations != null) {
            //It always wants to be null at first, and then I get errors for calling on null.
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot conv in foundConversations.docs) {
              Map<String, dynamic> convData = conv.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
              convCards.add(
                ConvCard(convData)  // A homemade widget that takes a Map argument to display some data from the conversation
              );
              // i++;
            }
          } else {
            // For as long as the found conversations are null, a spinner will be shown:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          // This part will only be reached if conversations were found:
          return ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            itemCount: convCards.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return convCards[index];
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you have any questions on that, I'm happy to answer.